# StringBuilder formatting with list

Tags: c#

I am having problems formatting a list with stringbuilder to output the way I need it. Basically need my list to drop a line every two values. For example I loop through a series of text boxes and add entered text to the list. I then loop through the list and  print or copy to clipboard the data:

```
List<string> listValues = new List<string>();          

StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

foreach (TextBox x in controlGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
{

    if (x.Text.Length > 0)
    {
       listValues.Add(x.Text);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < listValues.Count; i++)
{
    // formating code w/ listValues[i];            
}
```

I need it to format as such:

```
listValues[0] + " " + listValues[1]

listValues[2] + " " + listValues[3]

listValues[4] + " " + listValues[5]
```

which to the user would paste like:

> 1 foo
>
> 2 fooa
>
> 3 foob

I have searched around for a good bit and can't find a similar result so if the easy answer is out there I apologize for the repeat.

Thanks

Comment: Increment your loop by 2 and inside the loop use `i + 1` to access the next value?

Comment: ^-- This and exit condition should be `i < listValues.Count - 1`

Comment: You can use modulo `%` to detect when to newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you even need the list?  Just go straight into the StringBuilder like this?

```
bool first = true;
StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();            
foreach (TextBox x in controlGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (x.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        value.Append(first ? x.Text : " " + x.Text + "\r\n");
        first = !first;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
```

Comment: This works perfect for my needs. Thanks for the direction on it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, any reason not to use `x.Text + Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: No reason...I jump between a lot of languages and that's what came to mind first.  `Environment.NewLine` would be the most correct (if you are concerned with multiple platforms).

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ for the purpose.

```
var result = listValues.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2)
        .Select(x => string.Join(" ", x.Select(c => c.Value)));
```

Sample Input

```
1
Foo
2
fooa
3
foob
```

Output

```
1 Foo 
2 fooa 
3 foob
```